# R Shiny partial styling of validation message

Tags: r, validation, shiny, format

Consider the following validation statement:

```
validate(need(input$cost >= 0, "Please enter valid input for 'Cost'."))
```

How can I style the word 'Cost' in the error message (such as making it red) but leave the rest of the text to the default format?

Comment: I am not sure if you can partially style the error msg, as html tags are not interpreted there. I know, that you can style the whole error-messages, see this [link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I've seen that link; as you say might not be possible...